# Objects are not valid as react child -react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a object inside a variable called `clickedCountry` that has the structure `{name:x, population: x, region:x, capital: x...}`. I can access it via `clickedCountry.population`. However, if I want to access it programmatically (where I wrote, works not) I get

> Objects are not valid as React children

```js
{
  ['Name', 'Population', 'Region','Capital', 'Currencies', 'Languages'].map(el => {

    let name = el.toLowerCase()
    console.log(typeof(name)) //=>returns string
    console.log(name) //=> returns population, region etc.

    return (
      <Typography gutterBottom component="div">
        <span className='font-600'>{el}:</span> 
         {clickedCountry.name} //=> works
         {clickedCountry[name]}  //=> works not 
         {clickedCountry[`${name}`]} //=>works not
         {clickedCountry[`${el.toLowerCase()}`]} //=>works not 
      </Typography>
    )

  });

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `clickedCountry["Name"]`?

Comment: Just a quick question. clickedCountry.languages / currencies . Are those nested objects? If they are then that's the issue

Comment: That was exactly the issue, it was something like clickedCountry.currencies[0]?.name. Thanks Ryan and everyone answering!

Answer (score 0):

You are returning valid JSX for every element in your array.
You also need to return the mapped array.

You might want to do this

```js
{
return ['Name', 'Population', 'Region','Capital', 'Currencies', 'Languages'].map(el => {

    let name = el.toLowerCase()
    console.log(typeof(name)) //=>returns string
    console.log(name) //=> returns population, region etc.

    return (
      <Typography gutterBottom component="div">
        <span className='font-600'>{el}:</span> 
         {clickedCountry.name} //=> works
         {clickedCountry[name]}  //=> works not 
         {clickedCountry[`${name}`]} //=>works not
         {clickedCountry[`${el.toLowerCase()}`]} //=>works not 
      </Typography>
    )

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an array of objects that don't necessarily have the same keys, but you want to iterate over them anyway using the keys they *do* have to create some JSX.

Here we're passing in the data array as a component prop. We `map` over the array and for each object we get its keys (`Object.keys()` returns an array of its own). We then `map` over the keys array and for each object property with that key we return some JSX.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {  
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(obj => {
        const keys = Object.keys(obj);
        return (
          <div className="country">
            {keys.map(key => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <span className="label">{key}: </span>
                  {obj[key]}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const data = [
  { name: 'US', population: '320M', region: 'Georgia', continent: 'North America' },
  { name: 'Spain', population: '47M', capital: 'Madrid', anthem: 'Marcha Real', continent: 'Europe' }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.country { background-color: #efefef; padding: 0.2em; border: 1px solid #787878; }
.country:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 1em; }
.label { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```